# How can I convert String[][] to ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there any possibility to convert String[][] to ArrayList?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: `String[][]` is a two dimensional array. `ArrayList<String>` is one dimensional. Do you want `ArrayList<String[]>` or `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` or do you want to flatten/join the second dimension?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String[][] list = new String[3][2];
list[0][0] = "a";
list[0][1] = "b";
list[1][0] = "c";
list[1][1] = "d";
list[2][0] = "e";
list[2][1] = "f";

for (String[] sublist : list) {
    for (String string : sublist) {
        arrayList.add(string);
    }
}
System.out.println(arrayList);
```

This might not be the best way, but it works.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Directly, No. It is not possible. This is because an ArrayList is one dimensional, while your array is two dimensional. You have two options you can work with,

- Convert your 2d array into an array of ArrayLists
- flatten your 2d array into a 1d array, then convert that into an ArrayList